# Ionic Google Maps controller not restarting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

I have a list, and everytime I click on the list, I go to another tab which contains the map and shows the marker, but everytime I click on the list, it will add another marker, instead of refreshing the map and showing only one.

This is the code of my controller.

```js
app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, animalListServ) {

 $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
   var map;
   var mostrar = false;

   console.log("llegamos");
   var paramLongitude = $stateParams.longitude;
   var paramLatitude = $stateParams.latitude;
   var paramHealth = $stateParams.health;

   console.log(paramLongitude);
   console.log(paramLatitude);
   console.log(paramHealth);

   $timeout(function() { $scope.showMap(); }, 1000);

  $scope.showMap = function() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("map");

    //Initiate the map view
    map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

    map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
   }, false)
  };

   function onMapReady() {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 100;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();
    // img.src = array[i].image;
    img.src = 'img/dogstreet.jpg';


    img.onload = function() {

      context.drawImage(img, 0, 5, 90, 90);

      context.font = '12pt Calibri';
      // context.fillStyle = 'black';
      context.fillText(paramHealth, 95, 15);
      context.fillText('09/09/2016', 95, 45);

      var myLatlng = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(paramLatitude, paramLongitude);

      $scope.savedMarker = map.addMarker({
       position: myLatlng,
       title: canvas.toDataURL()
       
      }, function(marker) {
        marker.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MARKER_CLICK, function() {
         console.log("llegamos aqui?")
         marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
       });
    };

   }

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are keeping your previous map. So when you add a new maker it's been added to previous map.

I see different options here:

- Clear the map when you go back to the list. Just set the div html to ''.
- Another option will be to set different id's for every map div. Then pass the id to the function the create the maker. So you will have something like this:

  ```
  //...
  $scope.showMap = function(mapID) {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          var div = document.getElementById("map" + mapID);
  //...
  ```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer.  I tried what you said, but I can't destroy the map. As far as I know, you can only have 1 instance of the map, and can't be destroyed, if you call it again, will be the same map.